# How to insert image on the background (overlap with text) with add_picture() in python-docx?

Tags: image, overlay, docx, overlapping, python-docx

How can i insert images to background in text (like overlapping) by python-docx?

I know it is possible that the image can be placed with text on the right or left side on that.

but i want something like floating images over the any text. like background image.

it is possible do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Floating picture is not supported yet with `python-docx` v0.8.10. But based on the implementation of creating inline picture, I explored a workaround, and used in my project.

https://github.com/dothinking/pdf2docx/issues/54#issuecomment-715925252

The steps to explore floating image:

- create two docx files, one inserting an inline image and another a floating image (in this case, use `behind text` mode)
- check the difference of source xml between these two files
- implement floating image based on the observed structure and `python-docx` source code for inline image

xml structure results:

- inline image is a `<wp:inline>` node under `<w:drawing>`
- floating image is a `<wp:anchor>` node under `<w:drawing>`
- besides all sub-nodes of inline image, floating image contains also `<wp:positionH>` and `<wp:positionV>` to define the fixed position

So, the idea is to create `<wp:anchor>` node, then append sub-nodes: not only all the same nodes with inline image, but also the extra `<wp:positionH>` and `<wp:positionV>`.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

'''
Implement floating image based on python-docx 0.8.10.

- Text wrapping style: BEHIND TEXT <wp:anchor behindDoc="1">
- Picture position: top-left corner of PAGE `<wp:positionH relativeFrom="page">`.

Create a docx sample (Layout | Positions | More Layout Options) and explore the 
source xml (Open as a zip | word | document.xml) to implement other text wrapping
styles and position modes per `CT_Anchor._anchor_xml()`.
'''

from docx.oxml import parse_xml, register_element_cls
from docx.oxml.ns import nsdecls
from docx.oxml.shape import CT_Picture
from docx.oxml.xmlchemy import BaseOxmlElement, OneAndOnlyOne

# refer to docx.oxml.shape.CT_Inline
class CT_Anchor(BaseOxmlElement):
    """
    ``<w:anchor>`` element, container for a floating image.
    """
    extent = OneAndOnlyOne('wp:extent')
    docPr = OneAndOnlyOne('wp:docPr')
    graphic = OneAndOnlyOne('a:graphic')

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, cx, cy, shape_id, pic, pos_x, pos_y):
        """
        Return a new ``<wp:anchor>`` element populated with the values passed
        as parameters.
        """
        anchor = parse_xml(cls._anchor_xml(pos_x, pos_y))
        anchor.extent.cx = cx
        anchor.extent.cy = cy
        anchor.docPr.id = shape_id
        anchor.docPr.name = 'Picture %d' % shape_id
        anchor.graphic.graphicData.uri = (
            'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture'
        )
        anchor.graphic.graphicData._insert_pic(pic)
        return anchor

    @classmethod
    def new_pic_anchor(cls, shape_id, rId, filename, cx, cy, pos_x, pos_y):
        """
        Return a new `wp:anchor` element containing the `pic:pic` element
        specified by the argument values.
        """
        pic_id = 0  # Word doesn't seem to use this, but does not omit it
        pic = CT_Picture.new(pic_id, filename, rId, cx, cy)
        anchor = cls.new(cx, cy, shape_id, pic, pos_x, pos_y)
        anchor.graphic.graphicData._insert_pic(pic)
        return anchor

    @classmethod
    def _anchor_xml(cls, pos_x, pos_y):
        return (
            '<wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" simplePos="0" relativeHeight="0" \n'
            '           behindDoc="1" locked="0" layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="1" \n'
            '           %s>\n'
            '  <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/>\n'
            '  <wp:positionH relativeFrom="page">\n'
            '    <wp:posOffset>%d</wp:posOffset>\n'
            '  </wp:positionH>\n'
            '  <wp:positionV relativeFrom="page">\n'
            '    <wp:posOffset>%d</wp:posOffset>\n'
            '  </wp:positionV>\n'                    
            '  <wp:extent cx="914400" cy="914400"/>\n'
            '  <wp:wrapNone/>\n'
            '  <wp:docPr id="666" name="unnamed"/>\n'
            '  <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>\n'
            '    <a:graphicFrameLocks noChangeAspect="1"/>\n'
            '  </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>\n'
            '  <a:graphic>\n'
            '    <a:graphicData uri="URI not set"/>\n'
            '  </a:graphic>\n'
            '</wp:anchor>' % ( nsdecls('wp', 'a', 'pic', 'r'), int(pos_x), int(pos_y) )
        )


# refer to docx.parts.story.BaseStoryPart.new_pic_inline
def new_pic_anchor(part, image_descriptor, width, height, pos_x, pos_y):
    """Return a newly-created `w:anchor` element.

    The element contains the image specified by *image_descriptor* and is scaled
    based on the values of *width* and *height*.
    """
    rId, image = part.get_or_add_image(image_descriptor)
    cx, cy = image.scaled_dimensions(width, height)
    shape_id, filename = part.next_id, image.filename    
    return CT_Anchor.new_pic_anchor(shape_id, rId, filename, cx, cy, pos_x, pos_y)


# refer to docx.text.run.add_picture
def add_float_picture(p, image_path_or_stream, width=None, height=None, pos_x=0, pos_y=0):
    """Add float picture at fixed position `pos_x` and `pos_y` to the top-left point of page.
    """
    run = p.add_run()
    anchor = new_pic_anchor(run.part, image_path_or_stream, width, height, pos_x, pos_y)
    run._r.add_drawing(anchor)

# refer to docx.oxml.shape.__init__.py
register_element_cls('wp:anchor', CT_Anchor)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    from docx import Document
    from docx.shared import Inches, Pt

    document = Document()

    # add a floating image
    p = document.add_paragraph()
    add_float_picture(p, 'test.png', width=Inches(5.0), pos_x=Pt(20), pos_y=Pt(30))

    # add text
    p.add_run('Hello World'*50)


    document.save('output.docx')
```

Comment: Amazing complete example you provided, still working perfectly in 2024 and version 1.1.0. It would be great to include this in the actual docs as it helped me understand several things about how Word and the package work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work that when you insert an image in your template file in a table, that docx then Reimport the image

Comment: I create a headline table, insert an image, set it to background, set font size of table to 1, move outside lines for headline to the limit of the document and then save as template. After rewriting with docx your image will still be there and by this way you can set nice styles easily on documents.

Answer (score -1):

According to their [documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/shapes.html) as of now they only support inline pictures. I have the same problem.

So currently there is no way of doing that with python-docx

> Inline shapes are treated like a big text character (a character glyph). The line height is increased to accomodate the shape and the shape is wrapped to a line it will fit on width-wise, just like text. Inserting text in front of it will cause it to move to the right. Often, a picture is placed in a paragraph by itself, but this is not required. It can have text before and after it in the paragraph in which it’s placed.
>
> **At the time of writing, python-docx only supports inline pictures**. Floating pictures can be added. If you have an active use case, submit a feature request on the issue tracker. The Document.add_picture() method adds a specified picture to the end of the document in a paragraph of its own. However, by digging a little deeper into the API you can place text on either side of the picture in its paragraph, or both.